# Trying to build a script on python for FLIR lepton camera

Tags: python, windows, flir

I'm trying to build a script with GUI in windows by pycharm that will do:

1. The GUI will be like a form with details.
2. A button that will turn on the camera
3. By clicking the button the camera will shoot a video for 60 seconds.
4. Saving the video and uploading it to server(and/or local)

I'm using PureThermal 2 - FLIR Lepton Smart I/O Module  and windows 10.
I have problems with building the code to manage the camera.

if someone know/heard about project like this(only windows and python), 
l would like a link to the project or to the person.

I'm writing this question after searching the web for couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do that with tkinter really quickly.
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html
2. This is still a task for tkinter.
3. You might want to look into Flirpy. https://flirpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
4. This last part is something you can achieve with cv2.

Your question is really broad, please break it down into smaller parts next time to receive more specific answers.